# Run Docker with old computer

Tags: docker

I can't run docker (linux) containers on my PC - it is too slow for that. Is there other ways of running/developing/testing docker containers in a similar way to doing it on my PC? Maybe some browser app? Or the only option is to simply host a VM somewhere like DigitalOcean or AWS?

Comment: Use something like http://play-with-docker.com/ or take small VPS and used `DOCKER_HOST` variable and run the apps on VPS

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I am new to docker, so could you tell me what is `DOCKER_HOST` variable and how is it used?

Comment: Not sure how running code in a browser would be faster than directly in the VM, unless that browser is just a front end to a remote server. If you really want to speed it up, ditch the VM, run docker directly on a Linux OS, instead of Mac or Windows running Linux in the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AWS ECS. AWS gives you a free trial for 12 months where they give you some free stuff like free server hours and so on. After you create a new AWS account, go to AWS ECS service and then go to the repository section and create a new repository item by uploading your Docker image. Now go to the tasks section and create a task configuration for your docker image like memory, port and so on. After then, create a new service and assign it to the task that you just created and run it.

This process is straightforward and it will take you around an hour to finish all.

Follow the steps in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wLMLwjCqN4